# Make an implicit conversion operator preferred over another in C++

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, operator-precedence

I would like to prefer a certain implicit conversion sequence over another. I have the following (greatly simplified) class and functions:

```
class Whatever {...}

template <class T>
class ref
{
    public:

        operator T* ()
        {
            return object;
        }

        operator T& ()
        {
            return *object;
        }

        T* object;
        ...
};

void f (Whatever*)
{
    cout << "f (Whatever*)" << endl;
}

void f (Whatever&)
{
    cout << "f (Whatever&") << endl;
}

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
    ref<Whatever> whatever = ...;
    f(whatever);
}
```

When I have a ref object and I am making an ambiguous call to f, I would like the compiler to choose the one involving T&. But in other unambiguous cases I wish the implicit conversion to remain the same.

So far I have tried introducing an intermediate class which ref is implicitly convertible to, and which has an implicit conversion operator to T*, so the conversion sequence would be longer. Unfortunately it did not recognize in unambiguous cases that it is indeed convertible to T*. Same thing happened when the intermediate class had a(n implicit) constructor. It's no wonder, this version was completely unrelated to ref.

I also tried making one of the implicit conversion operators template, same result.

Comment: A reference and a pointer aren't _all_ that different.  Is it absolutely necessary to have both, and not just a pointer?

Comment: Well it isn't absolutely necessary since workarounds are easy, but it would certainly be much nicer and cleaner. I already had problems with streaming a `ref<int> x` to cout, since it can mean `cout << (int*) x` and `cout << (int)x` as well.

Comment: I've just read that the standard only allows 1 user defined conversion in a conversion sequence. God damn it! Though is it only for implicit conversion operators or constructors as well?

Comment: "At most one user-defined conversion (constructor or conversion function) is implicitly applied to a single value."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple: define `void f(const ref<Whatever>&)`, it will trump the others which require a conversion.

Comment: I do not necessarily have access to f.

Comment: @Frigo: You can define additional overloads in your own code, you don't need the source code for `f(Whatever&)`.

Comment: I'll accept this answer. With this and the SFINAE return type extraction, it is possible to prefer the function accepting reference, if it exists. Most useful for operators, they fully solve the problem there (bar a GCC bug). Still no good for unknown functions, in those cases the user needs to explicitly declare which one does he want. Still, good enough.

Answer (score 1):

There's no "ranking" among the two conversions; both are equally good and hence the overload is ambiguous. That's a core part of the language that you cannot change.

However, you can just specify which overload you want by making the conversion explicit:

```
f((Whatever&) whatever);
```

Comment: Yeah, I kinda wanted to avoid explicit conversion. Even without precedence among implicit conversion operators, are there any way to trick the compiler into choosing the one with the reference?

Comment: @Frigo: I don't think there's anything you can do. Either don't have the two overloads of `f`, or don't offer both conversion operators implicitly, or use the explicit conversion.

Answer (score 0):

Only one user-defined conversion function is applied when performing implicit conversions. If there is no defined conversion function, the compiler does not look for intermediate types into which an object can be converted.

Comment: I tried defining two class templates with constructors from ref<T>, but the compiler does not recognize the conversion, probably due to them being templates. I tried explicitly instantiating them in ref, but looks like it does not accept the syntax of explicit instantiation inside another class.

Comment: "does NOT look" ah, I completely missed that little word there